# Generator object to produce kwargs mapping for function

Tags: python, dictionary, generator, keyword-argument

I have a generalised generator function, which maps delimited strings to a which yields a kwargs-type dictionary object from a list of delimited strings.

I'd like to use the kwargs-type dictionaries as arguments in another generator function. However, I get the message

> edge_generator() argument after ** must be a mapping, not generator

Here is my current, broken code:

```
def line_from_file_generator(file_name):

    with open(file_name) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            yield line

def map_delimited_lines_to_kwargs(lines, delimiter, kwarg_index_map):

    for line in lines:

        kwargs = {}
        args = line.strip().split(delimiter)

        for kwarg, index in kwarg_index_map.items():
            kwargs[kwarg] = args[index]

        yield kwargs


def edge_generator(source_node_name, destination_node_name, weights):

    for line in lines:
        yield Edge(source_node_name, destination_node_name, weights)


lines = line_from_file_generator('mit_map.txt')
kwarg_index_map = {'source_node_name': 0, 'destination_node_name': 1, 'weights': 2}
kwarg_collection = map_delimited_lines_to_kwargs(lines, ' ', kwarg_index_map)
edges = edge_generator(**kwargs_collection)
```

I now understand why this is wrong (a generator is a kind of sequence, not a mapping (dict that can be expanded)).

Can I get around this whilst keeping the abstractions I have created? What would the code be? I've tried changing the last line to the below, but it fails to iterate through the kwargs generator, and all edges are generated with the same arguments.

`edges = edge_generator(**kwarg_collection.next())`

Comment: At a first glance, your `map_delimited_lines_to_kwargs()` should simply *return* a single kwargs dict after the loop (and initialize it before the loop, of course), rather than yielding one each time through the loop.

Comment: @jasonharper - yes, I think you are right. This simplifies things a great deal! I think I went overboard with the generator functions. It's my first time using them...

Comment: @jasonharper, saying that, I do lose the benefit of using a generator when using the edges to then build a graph later on, because I have to materialise all of the kwargs for generating edges ahead of time. I found another way to do this however which I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work. Instead of trying to expand the arguments for the Edge generator in the function definition, I simply passed the kwargs generator whole, and added a loop over the kwargs generator in the body of the Edge generator, and expanded the arguments when creating the edge.

```
def line_from_file_generator(file_name):

    with open(file_name) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            yield line


def kwargs_from_delimited_strings_generator(lines, delimiter, kwarg_index_map):

    for line in lines:

        kwargs = {}
        args = line.strip().split(delimiter)

        for kwarg, index in kwarg_index_map.items():
            kwargs[kwarg] = args[index]

        yield kwargs


def edge_generator(kwargs_collection):

    for kwargs in kwargs_collection:
        yield Edge(**kwargs)


lines_from_file = line_from_file_generator('mit_map.txt')
kwarg_index_map = {'source_node_name': 0, 'destination_node_name': 1,
                   'weights': 2}
kwargs_from_delimited_strings = kwargs_from_delimited_strings_generator(
                                    lines_from_file, ' ', kwarg_index_map)
edges_from_kwargs = edge_generator(kwargs_from_delimited_strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might modify your program.

Note that I delay using the `**` operator for as long as possible. In fact, I don't use it until I have a single concrete `dict`.

Note that `edge_generator` iterates on its argument, not `lines`. I'm not sure where `lines` was supposed to come from, anyway.

Note that the chain of generators is preserved. The complete set of edges is not constructed until the `list()` constructor is applied to the final generator.

```
def Edge(source_node_name, destination_node_name, weights):
    '''Testing version of Edge()'''
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(source_node_name, destination_node_name, weights)

def line_from_file_generator(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:
            yield line

def map_delimited_lines_to_kwargs(lines, delimiter, kwarg_index_map):
    for line in lines:
        kwargs = {}
        args = line.strip().split(delimiter)

        for kwarg, index in kwarg_index_map.items():
            kwargs[kwarg] = args[index]

        yield kwargs

def edge_generator(edge_attribute_dicts):
    for attribute_dict in edge_attribute_dicts:
        yield Edge(**attribute_dict)

lines = line_from_file_generator('mit_map.txt')
kwarg_index_map = {
    'source_node_name': 0,
    'destination_node_name': 1,
    'weights': 2}
kwargs_collection = map_delimited_lines_to_kwargs(lines, ' ', kwarg_index_map)
edges = edge_generator(kwargs_collection)
print(list(edges))
```